Android device can no longer be paired via ADB WiFi
After installing and setting of adb, my smartphone worked flawlessly for more than a month via adb WiFi connection. Today, for some unknown reason, I was unable to pair my device via WiFi. I haven't updated anything on my comp and phone. I didn't enable/disable any additional features. I use the same android project. Reinstallation of adb did nothing. Pairing using QR-code and digit-code doesn't work at all, that's the reason I used adb. Troubleshoot Device Connections window doesn't help either.
Question: How can I pair my device to Android Studio (Koala) again via adb WiFi?

Just making sure if you tried shutting down the phone and restarting the phone.

Yes, Morrison, and not only the phone but also the comp.

Things you've probably tried: double checking for any firewall on PC/Wifi access point, reset/wipe the adb (vendor) keys, additionally Android 11 - Wireless ADB Pairing - Windows machine as you don't mention what PC OS you are using.

Have a mac. No firewall. I tried adb uninstall/install. Tried adb kill-server / adb start-server. Tried to remove existing authorized adb keys. Nothing helps.

I finally found a solution to my problem. I connected the device via cable, enabled USB debugging and applied the Revoke USB debugging authorizations command. Turned off USB debug, turned on WiFi debug. After that, adb WiFi debugging has been working as expected. Here's a menu path:
Settings > Developer options > Revoke USB debugging authorizations
